# How can I trigger every 1 second with Jetpack compose animation?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

At the moment, I am using this.

```
val animateble = remember { Animatable(0f) }
val animateIndex = animateble.value.toInt()
        .coerceIn(0..numberPad.size)
val speed = 2000

LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
    animateble.animateTo(
        targetValue = numberPad.size.toFloat(),
        animationSpec = tween(durationMillis = speed * numberPad.size)
    ) {
        Log.d("aos", "value: $value")
      }
}
```

```
LazyRow(
    horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(7.dp),
    modifier = Modifier
                .alpha(animateIndex / rowIndex.toFloat())
)
```

What I am trying to do is giving fade in animation from the top row to the bottom row one by one.

This code seems like using the MainThread too much because it uses float value. So, it sometimes freezes, and I am looking for any other way that I can do with Int. like a timer.

Is there any animation that fits in my case?

Comment: What makes you think changing Float to Int is going to improve anything?

Comment: @m0skit0 whenever the value changes, the composable function is also affected and it seems like the MainThread becomes busy.

Comment: Isn't that precisely what you want? Or sorry I didn't understand the problem.

Comment: I just want the UI get affected every N seconds. Not, 0.1111, 2.2333, 4.3334 seconds or something. But, 1, 2, 3, 4, ... the UI looks slow when it comes to float. I mean, my example in the question.

Answer (score 0):

this snippet might help you, run a infinite loop delayed by one second in each iteration and gets stopped during decomposition

```
val colors = listOf(Color.Red, Color.Green, Color.Yellow)

@Composable
fun Compose() {

    var sec by remember {
        mutableStateOf(0)
    }

    LaunchedEffect(key1 = Unit, block = {
        while (true) {
            delay(1000)
            sec += 1000
        }
    })

    val nextColor by remember(sec) {
        mutableStateOf(colors.random())
    }

    val text by remember(sec) { mutableStateOf("$sec") }
    val color by animateColorAsState(targetValue = nextColor)

    Text(text = text, color = color)

}
```

Comment: well, while loop looks dangerous. Is this a best practice?

Comment: yes because here we are using it inside a coroutine, loops along with coroutine scope get canceled when decomposition happens,  this is what I found on its official docs "coroutine will be cancelled when the LaunchedEffect leaves the composition" so its  completely  safe plus we are also using delay inside while loop

Comment: https://androidx.tech/artifacts/compose.animation/animation-core/1.0.0-beta09-source/androidx/compose/animation/core/InfiniteTransition.kt.html look at line no 133 or seach for LaunchedEffect internally they are also using same technique